# Sass ampersand to select element with second class but also extend name

Tags: sass

I have the following classes on an element:

```
<div class="scene scene__1"></div>
```

and I would like to select it the [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) way:

```
.scene {
  & &__1 {
   /* do something */
  }    
}
```

but this does not work.

Neither does `&&__1 { }` or `&.& { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) on the second ampersand to get the desired result:

```
.scene {
  &#{&}__1 {
   /* do something */
  }    
}
```

It will compile as `.scene.scene__1`